# Wire app ver 33.2872 from Ubuntu 18.4.1 repo,

Tags: permissions

I and a small group are all using the "Wire" app, from the Ubuntu repo, one person reports that he cannot change permissions (on clicking the shield on the Wire, app,wire.com), he gets the message "Wire is in Private  Mode", and permissions on the Wire website, cannot be changed for allowing webcam, and microphone.
  all are using Ubuntu 18.04.1, and Firefox 63.0.3.
  I would be grateful to know if anyone else has that problem, and a way to get "Wire" out of private mode.
Thank you.
Regards.
Chris.

Answer (score 1):

So I have sorted this question myself, the answer is simple. As the Wire App uses Firefox, it turns out that the persons Firefox was set to "always use private browsing", once this was altered in settings, the problem was resolved with the Wire App!
Thank you.
Chris.